# Java: Fetching Lowest Level Class an Object Belongs to

Tags: java

So, lets say I have a class, `TopLevel`, and I have two more classes, `BottomLevelOne extends TopLevel`, and `BottomLevelTwo extends TopLevel`. Without explicitly checking `variable instanceof BottomLevelOne`, `variable instanceof BottomLevelTwo`, and `variable instanceof TopLevel`, is there a way, possibly using Reflection or something, which would allow me to fetch the Bottom Level class something belongs to.

For instance, `new BottomLevelOne().getLowestLevelClass()` may return `BottomLevelOne.class`

EDIT: Sorry, I should mention I am casting it to the TopLevel class before checking, as I am giving it to a function.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention I am casting it first.

Comment: Casting doesn't change an object.

Comment: `Object.getClass()` will always return the type of the `Object`. Casting does not change the underlying type of the `Object`, it merely changes the type of the reference.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you, learned something today.

Answer (score 2):

As [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) and  [Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) mentioned, casting does not change the results of `Object.getClass()`. Thank you, [Sotirios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) and [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider)!